# Creating Javascript Object by id using jQuery selector from an external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

My project has 3 files - a **onesphere.html** file, **main.js** file and an **x3dSphere.js** file.

In **main.js** I am trying to create an object defined by the **x3dSphere.js** file by id. As shown here:

**x3dSphere.js**

```
//x3dSphere "Class" Definition
function x3dSphere(id) {
    this.id = "#"+id;
    this.position = $(id).attr('translation');
    this.diffuseColor = $(id).attr('diffuseColor');
}
```

**main.js**

```
//main.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveShapes").click(function() {
        var string = $("#b1").attr('translation'); //works
        alert(string);
        var ball = new x3dSphere("b1"); //does not work
        alert(ball.position);
    });
});
```

When I read the translation value using the jQuery id selector from **main.js** it works and the string alert works however when I try to create an object it fails. For some reason it is not selecting the specific transform element when I use my object.The first alert correctly prints out "0 0 0" and the second alert is coming across as 'undefined'.

This first image is snap of the watch expressions in Firefox when in the *x3dSphere.js object file* https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLRmM.png

This first image is snap of the watch expressions in Firefox when in the *main.js file* https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqKI0.png

(sorry I don't have the reputation to post images yet)

As you can see the object method doesn't pick up < transform#b1 > and I'm not sure why. I think it might have something to do with the fact that this object/ "class" definition is in a separate file.

Attached is my full html file so you can see the format of the element I am trying to select as well as how I included the multiple script files.

**onesphere.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>X3D</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spheres.css"></link>
    <script src="js/lib/x3dom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/x3dSphere.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Ball </h1>
    <div id="x3dcontent">
    <button id="moveShapes" >Move Shapes</button>
    <x3d width="500px" height="400px">
        <scene>
            <transform id="b1" DEF="b1" translation='0 0 0'>
                <shape>
                    <appearance>
                        <material diffuseColor='1 0 0'></material>
                    </appearance>

                    <sphere></sphere>
                </shape>
            </transform>
        </scene>
    </x3d>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I change x3dSphere.js to get the alert to print out "0 0 0"? Is it possible to keep x3dSphere as a separate javascript file?

Comment: any errors thrown when you try to call `var ball = new x3dSphere("b1"); `?

Comment: I didn't get any errors when creating the object. Turns out I just needed to add "this" instead like @Sean pointed out. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines in **x3dSphere.js**:

```
this.position = $(id).attr('translation');
this.diffuseColor = $(id).attr('diffuseColor');
```

should be:

```
this.position = $(this.id).attr('translation');
this.diffuseColor = $(this.id).attr('diffuseColor');
```

By using just `id` and not `this.id`, you are passing `"b1"` to jQuery instead of `"#b1"`.

Comment: Yeah that's right I didn't catch that. Thank you very much that fixes it. I'm new to objects so sometimes I forget what "this" is. Thanks again!